# Почему запись в RWStructuredBuffer в ComputeShader(hlsl, DirectX11) такая дорогая?

Tags: c++, direct3d, hlsl

Группы потоков распределены так:
Dispatch(1920 / 8, 1080 / 8, 1);
Я привязываю UAV(RWStructuredBuffer) к вычислительному шейдеру:

```
RWTexture2D<float4> Result : register(u0);

[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void main(uint3 threadID : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{

}
```

Да, в данном примере я использую RWTexture2D, но это сути не меняет(изменение fps примерно одинаковое), просто так удобнее показать.
Используя такой код, fps = 1500, но как только я добавляю одну строчку:

```
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void main(uint3 threadID : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    Result[threadID.xy] = 1;
}
```

И в там случае fps снижается до цифры 800, то есть потеря в 700 fps. По моему это как то не нормально, почему так может быть? Подозреваю что проблема в не правильном распределении потков.

Приведу ещё один пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код вы можете видеть на заднем плане. Я запустил своё приложение, и выводу частоту кадров с помощью Bandicam.

А вот работа другого шейдера(правда пиксельного), который выполняет трассировку лучей:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Частота кадров лишь чуть чуть больше в первом примере(ComputeShader), при том что код во втором примере(PixelShader) в разы сложнее и дороже, в отличии от простого умножения в Compute shader. А ведь это простое умножения 3 раза, тогда на сколько сильно будет снижатся fps при более сложных операциях. По всей видемости на много, но в чём смысл тогда вообще таких шейдеров, если они на столько не эффективны(уверн что, что то я не так делаю, так блин не должно быть)

Comment: Используйте метку [tag:directx] в сочетании с меткой используемого языка программирования, а также, по возможности, меткой конкретного API - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/directx/info.

Comment: т.е. это замедление fps по сравнению с шейдером, который ничего не делает?

Comment: @user7860670 да, логично что замедление будет, но блин на 700 fps из за простого приравнивания, по моему это слишком. Я пока искал как испаравить эту проблему, увидел как один человек не просто приравнивает, а ещё и умножает, и плюс к тому на значение из другого буфера, и у него 1500 fps. У меня же из за простого приравнивания к еденичке, fps пдает на 700 едениц. По моему это не нормально

Comment: @karmik метки исправил, спасибо

Comment: и что, запустив код этого человека, он у вас так же 1500 fps показывает?

Comment: @user7860670 ладно чел, я не знаю, может у него супер комп, но сути не меняет. Скажи мне, сильный ли это спад fps при таком почти не нагружающем коде?

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что этот код "почти не нагружающий". Тут же по сути чистый fill rate для uav буфера. Сравнивайте с результатом `ClearRenderTargetView` или чего-то подобного.

Comment: @user7860670 ладно, я сделал правку в вопросе, и показал ещё некоторые примеры. Это точно нормальное понижение fps?

Comment: что-то у вас все совсем запущенно... Вам стоит почитать про то, что не следует постить текст в виде картинок, что не следует измерять производительность в отладочном режиме, и про то, как создавать [mcve]. Я хз что вы намерили. Производительность стоит проверять посредством встроенного в студию профилировщика directx и/или xperf. Что касается собственно производительности, то у вас же тут практически самый быстрый случай - нет ни барьеров, ни пересекающихся атомарных операций. По идее это будет медленнее обычной записи разве что из-за потенциального отсутствия стриминга через кеш.

Comment: Видимо у меня и в правду всё запущено, ибо я очень многого не понял из того, что вы сказали. Баръеры? Атомарные операции? стриминг через кэш? А по поводу поста текста в виде картинок, суть была не в тексте, а в том, что на первой  картинке кода мало(Код с первой картинки я вам показывал писал через текст), а на второй картинке кода много, то есть там априори больше операций, чем 3 умножения, как минимум можно просто сравнить результаты, чёрный экран, и преломление света в сфере  фоном(я конечно мог бы скинуть вам код, но разве вы будете пытаться разобраться в моём трассировщике путей?).

Comment: @user7860670 Но ладно, попробую изучить профилировщик directx, может что то и получится узнать, если что, покажу результаты откладки, если вам это поможет понять в чём может быть проблема, и помочь. Кстати, раньше вы уже отвечали на другой мой вопрос, помните? Просто к слову :)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/allmemorybarrierwithgroupsync https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-advanced-stages-cs-atomic-functions при обычном рендеринге входные и выходные данные не пересекаются поэтому не надо заботится о когерентности кеша и т.п. а рабочий пример надо было делать чтобы хоть кто-то еще мог воспроизвести (или нет) такие же результаты

Comment: Сейчас вписал код трассировки лучей из пиксельного шейдереа в ComputeShader, и показатели fps были одинаковы(в ComputeShader даже чуть выше). Но как только я начинаю менять не только цвет пикселей на выходной текстурке, но ещё и менять структуру(структура ray, которая является UAV, также как и выходная текстура) фпс с 700 падает до 90. Вообще, я так понял это и есть та самая когерентность кеша? Надо бы почитать, и придумать как это всё устроить. Кстати, благодаря вам, я узнал про такую крутую штуку как анализатор графики Visual studio(правда пришлось повозиться с одной ошибкой), спасибо :)